# Signal Processing - Analysing the highest signal peak and time frame

Tags: java, android, algorithm, signal-processing, accelerometer

I've never touched anything to do with signal processing (Accelerometer sensor).  I've got some values from x,y,z axis and have a threshold set for each axis such that when it reaches a certain threshold, I will need to analyse the signal and how quickly it got to that threshold.

Basically I need to think of an algorithm for calculating the blue line from the diagram below when the signal hits the Y axis threshold.

All the Y axis signals are stored within an ArrayList .  I'm just wondering how I would calculate it.

[image: Signal]

Comment: For the most simple case: Find the index *i* of the first value in your list which is above the threshold, then, from index *i+1*, go on through your list, counting the steps until you find the first value below your threshold. - This "algorithm" is for the simplest of cases and I believe it will not get you very far by itself. (Keywords: "Noise", jitter, frequency,...)

Answer (score 0):

You could try integrating all the values above some threshold, and estimating the pulse duration from the peak and the total energy.

Comment: How would I do that? My friend was mentioning checking how many steps it took to reach the threshold.  Such that signal 1 on the left of my diagram could take 100 steps longer then signal 2 on the right?